# From Docker Wordpress to Docker Azure Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, azure, docker-compose

I have a  running dev installation of a dockerized wordpress project( via docker-compose) and was wondering what would be the best approach to deploying it to Azure. Most tutorials assume you are starting from scratch however I already have an installation and was wondering if I just need to integrate the azure-cli to the compose or setup an azure and migrate what was already done.

I have an account but do I invoke a docker VM or a wordpress from azure ??

What about the database?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest path is for you to create a new [Azure Container Service](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/container-service/), which can host Docker Swarm, and deploy it there. Install the Azure CLI 2.0 on your machine and follow the [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-service/dcos-swarm/container-service-deployment) to get started.